# Embeddable HTML editor/viewer web-app

Tags: web-apps, html-editor

I am looking for a web-app that allows me to type and view HTML code side-by-side (like on [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)). I want it it:

- have intellisense
- be online
- be embeddable into my webpage
- allow me to access previously worked on code via a login system, probably

I have some HTML and CSS experience but my skills are mainly in programming (C++, Java, etc.). I would make my own, but I can't seem to grasp how to embed the compiler with intellisense and could not find any open source code online.

Is anyone able to suggest a tool or piece of software in order to embed such an editor?

Comment: If I get you right, you are looking for a Html Live Editor?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations - I've edited your question to make it more clear, and less 'how do I do this' to make it more on topic. If you feel I've changed something that alters the original meaning, feel free to [edit] your question :)

Answer (score 1):

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

Is the web app you are looking for.

#### Feature Set

- Free
- Embed-able
- Online Editor
- Instant Preview
- Saves your code in your account
- Not sure about intellisense

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/):

- free
- web-app
- save to your account on the website
- use CSS, JS, and HTML
- can do live collaboration via a link, and chat/talk via the web-app
- has 'intellisense' for HTML, CSS, and JS
- live updating on the right

It's basically the same as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), but you can save the code, and collaborate with other people.

Now, I don't know exactly what you mean by 'embedding' - do you want to embed the result? Or code? If you want to embed the result, you can download the zip file of your JS, CSS and HTML code, or a single HTML file to use in a site, as an iframe or a page itself.

[image]
[image]
<sup>(Click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Can it be embedded into your own website? I guess asker wants an HTML snippet + necessary JS/CSS files.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yeah that's what I didn't understand. He didn't exactly mention *what* needs to be embedded - but the output can be downloaded, so I guess this has everything *but* the embedding feature :(

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is more what w3schools has when you click "Try it Yourself" with a text editor on the left and the output on the right, only I'd like the text editor to have intellisense a-la notepad++.

Comment: @user3625087 then this is what you want! It is exactly like w3schools w work intellisense